# Versions Maven Plugin update-parent checks online maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, versions-maven-plugin

I have 2 maven projects in- parent and child, both having 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.

The pom of parent:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.tmn</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>parent</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

</project>
```

The pom of child:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.tmn</groupId>
  <artifactId>child</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
      <groupId>com.tmn</groupId>
      <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <name>child</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

</project>
```

I updated the version of the parent pom to some release version, say 1.0.0 and did `mvn clean install` on my parent. So, my maven local repo contains the released pom. Now, I want to update the parent.version and the version of my child pom. I run

```
mvn versions:update-parent -DparentVersion=1.0.0 -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/repo
```

I want it to blindly update the parent.version to the parentversion I supply in my command. But I get this WARNING and it is not updated.

```
artifact com.tmn:parent: checking for updates 
[WARNING] Not updating version: could not resolve any versions
```

There is a similar issue logged here but I didn't understand the solution to this: https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/121

Comment: I am not sure about the syntax of  `-DparentVersion=1.0.0`, I would try `[1.0.0]` or `[1.0.0,1.0.0]` instead of `1.0.0`, but I am not sure.

Comment: In a multi module you should use the same version for parent and childs which can be achieved by using `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.0 -DgenerateBackupPoms=false`

Comment: @khmarbaise When I run your command only project.version gets updated. Not parent.version. Which brings me back to square 1.

Comment: Have you started it from the root where the list of modules has been defined ? I doubt that...

Comment: The child is not a module of the parent. I have a separate aggregate pom for that. When I update the version for the aggregator pom using the set command, all aggregator module pom's versions also get updated. But the module's parent.version does not.